# MMenu wont install on wordpress

Tags: installation

When I try to install the plugin, I get an error stating that there is no approved plugin in the package, so there is nothing to install.

I bought the full version, so would like to install the menu

tried to install at "add plugin", not approved

Comment: If you *bought*  that plugin, you should contact their support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.